# Integrate socially

Tags: phrases, expressions

I want to highlight the aspect of socially integrating with a team as well as integrating with the team's work flow.

Personally I think that when using 'integrate' in regards to 'integrating with a team', it sounds more focused toward work flow than in a social aspect. The same of 'becoming one of the team'. Is this the case?

If so, any suggestions for phrases or expressions to use in a professional sense? For example, on a curriculum vitae.

Comment: So you're looking for a descriptive term to use in a CV?

Comment: @J_LV Yes, so ideally succinct.

Comment: (Good) team-player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*adaptable*, *team-oriented*, *team-minded* seem like proper word choices to describe someone who possesses the traits characterized in your question.

This how I'd rank them from best to worst fit:

1. Team-oriented
2. Team-minded
3. Adaptable

They all work. However, as *adaptable* doesn't necessarily convey the social aspect I put it in third place. *Team-oriented* is more common than *team-minded*, at least in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I like the term *assimilate*, as it has a very cultural, ergo social, connotation.

Comment: Your post would be improved if it included a reference supporting your assertion.
See [how to answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That concept relates more to receiving party than the one coming in to join.